# vuejs not rending data 2nd time when data as updated using ajax

Tags: ajax, vue.js, vue-component

Im using vue js to update a few things on my page, its real simple use case

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
    template: '.....<a v-on:click="myfunction">data</a>{{stuff}}'
    data: {
        stuff: 0
    }

    mounted(){
        let __this = this;
        axios.....then(function (data){ __this.stuff = 1l }); // works

    }

    methods: {
                myfunction: function(){
                    this.stuff = 2;    /// dosnt work. template not rendered
                }
            }
    });
```

Any particular way to set the variable to detect changes or any pointers ? thanks.

Comment: Make sure you've defined `methods` outside of `mounted()`?

Comment: formatting error sorry, fixed it the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reusable components, your `data` field should actually be a function that returns the data object:

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
    template: '.....<a v-on:click="myfunction">data</a>{{stuff}}',
    data() {
        return {
            stuff: 0
        };
    },

    mounted(){
        let __this = this;
        axios.....then(function (data){ __this.stuff = 1l }); // works
    },
    methods: {
        myfunction: function(){
            this.stuff = 2;    // should work now
        }
    }
});
```

Please review [the relevant section of the Vue.js documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function) for more information concerning this issue.